# I made an edit to a post and a editor stole it

Tags: discussion, review, suggested-edits, attribution

A couple of days ago I made an edit to a post, after a few minutes, I guess a reviewer, edited the post precisely how I edited the post and did not say I edited the post.

Is there anything that can be done from people stealing edits?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about paranoia.

Comment: Your edit wasn't stolen (not that that's really possible, you are gifting it to the internet), it was improved on. Look at the "improve" part of the duplicate link

Comment: "Stealing" would likely be "improving" but deeming the suggestion unhelpful without changing anything else (or just one character).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Before accusing people of stealing, you might want to check out your [suggested edit history](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1505327/vis-15?tab=activity&sort=suggestions)

You've suggested 5 edits, all 5 were approved and 2 of those approvals were approved further.  You still received the rep, and the edits were still [attributed](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/19311740/revisions) [to you](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/19350181/revisions).

Answer (score 12):

You've suggested a total of 4 edits and all of them were approved. You got 8 reputation and nothing was "stolen".

Answer (score 8):

When you suggest a edit your suggestion will be reviewed by higher reputation users.

Here are the rules how it works:

> When improving an edit, the reviewer also has the option of marking the suggested edit as helpful or not helpful, which alters the outcome of the edit they make.
>
> **When the reviewer marks the edit as helpful:**
>
> The change history records the suggested edit and the improved edit as separate events.
>   The original editor still gets +2 reputation for their suggestion.
>
> **When the reviewer marks the edit as not helpful:**
>
> The change history records the improved edit only and the suggested edit is not shown.
>   The original editor does not get any reputation for their suggestion.

You might want to read more [**in this post**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76251/how-do-suggested-edits-work)

Answer (score 7):

Nobody "stole" any of your edits. I suspect you're confused because your name doesn't appear on all the posts you edited.

Each post (question or answer) shows the author of the original post and the author of the *most recent* edit. You have to view the edit history to see the authors of other edits.

You've suggested 5 edits, all of which were approved, and you received +2 reputation for each of them.

For 3 of the posts for which you suggested edits, someone else edited the posts *after* you did. As a result, your name doesn't appear on the post itself, but your name and your edit do appear in all 5 posts' edit histories.

To see the edit history of a post, click on the "edited 1 hour ago" link (or whatever the time happens to be) below the post.